# How to justify footnotes in two columns microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Microsoft word document with two columns on each page with equal width and specific distance between columns. I want to place a footnote under the first column. Columns are justified. I want to justify footnote with columns as well but there's no way of selecting both texts of columns and footnotes and selecting justify. Also, selecting footnotes alone and selecting justify does not work.
This is footnote part of my current document. Text in columns are black and footnote text is red.

[image: My current document]

And this is how it should look:
[image]

Unfortunately, when you select footnote, you cannot set the layout to columns of specified width and space between, unlike the original text.
Another problem is that my current footnotes spans the whole page, but in the template the footnotes spans only one column.

Thanks.